# software-center problem

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, virtualbox, software-center

I am not able to run any software from software-center, an error massage is shown at the time of running of software-center.

[image]

Terminal output:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list like:

sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

Look for any lines that do NOT start with deb. Your very first line is probably the bad one. They are probably garbage characters, or some other invalid text. Delete them, saving only the deb line. Save and close the file with control-o and control-x.

Open Synaptic from the Dash, and click the Reload button. Any remaining errors will show up.

Comment: Status please. Cheers, Al